# getting results(only numbers) into label, selecting radiobutton and checkbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need to get `results(price)` into a  label selecting by `radiobuttion` and `checkbox` and in the end need to add them up. I need to get all the results in a label.

> need to get result in label(cost excl. VAT)

[image]

> list of radiobutton and checkboxes

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To build on what Matt Stannett said, The `Calculate` method would actually be the `Changed` event handler for all the Checkboxes and Radiobuttons.  Basically, anytime anything is changed, recalculate the value and display it of the label.

Comment: could you please give me an example how to use that event with checkbox or radiobutton. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into the [CheckBox.CheckedChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and [RadioButton.CheckChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) events then have some sort of `Calculate` method that sets the [Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the label.